# How to fetch only certain fields with query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I use doctrine to fetch data from the database.
In my repository, I build the query

```
createQueryBuilder('p')
->select('p, bc, cp')
->innerJoin('p.customer', 'bc')
->innerJoin('bc.person', 'cp')
```

It works well for me, I get the data. But how can I say to doctrine to give me not all fields, but only certain fields, like p.id, p.name, cp.firstname etc?

Thank's for your answers.

Comment: [How can I select specific Columns with createQueryBuilder in ORM Symfony2?] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543650/how-can-i-select-specific-columns-with-createquerybuilder-in-orm-symfony2)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726879/select-specific-columns-from-a-repository-in-doctrine-2] (Select specific columns from a repository in Doctrine 2)

Comment: It doesn't work for me:
I write 
select(['p.id', 'bc', 'cp'])

and I get an error:


[Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT p.id,': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query->createQueryBuilder()
->select('p.id','p.name', 'bc.xyz', 'cp.xyz')
->from('entity','p')
->innerJoin('p.customer', 'bc')
->innerJoin('bc.person', 'cp');
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

I have this line and works like a charm ->select('p', 'p.id', 'cp.id') you need to select one root, in this case my root is p and then you can choose certain fields, Good luck !

Comment: Take a look on the generated SQL-statement (not DQL). You will see, that doctrine has generated the SQL-Statement with ALL fields from the table with alias p and additionally one more time the fields p.id.

Comment: in that case you need to do someting like this:
 $order = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT o.id AS orderId, i.id AS itemID FROM PayBundle:Order o LEFT JOIN o.items i')->getResult();

if you need more documentation you can check this link: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: if i do:


`$query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT fp.id, bc, cp.firstname FROM \FactoKisBundle\Entity\Facto\Process fp INNER JOIN fp.customer bc INNER JOIN bc.person cp');` 


I receive

SELECT fp.id,': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.

Comment: you need to be more specific with bc entity, someting like this : $query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT fp.id, bc.id, bc.name, cp.firstname FROM \FactoKisBundle\Entity\Facto\Process fp INNER JOIN fp.customer bc INNER JOIN bc.person cp');

Comment: It works, Thank you very much.
I should'n mix entities and entities field in the same query. 
Either SELECT fp.id, bc.id, cp.firstname or SELECT fp, bc, cp

Answer (score 0):

```
$fields = array('p.id', 'p.name', 'cp.firstname');

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query
    ->select($fields)
    ->from('xxxBundle:xxx', 'p')
    ->innerJoin('p.customer', 'bc')
    ->innerJoin('bc.person', 'cp')

$results = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

more details ....

1. [Doctrine won't let me select specific fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465353/doctrine-wont-let-me-select-specific-fields)
2. [How can I select specific Columns with createQueryBuilder in ORM Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543650/how-can-i-select-specific-columns-with-createquerybuilder-in-orm-symfony2)

Comment: if you don't specify the alias you get `Too few arguments to function Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder(), 0 passed`